# Check page title is contained within link attribute and assign active class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a jQuery function to change the colour of the link of my navigation bar. I want to identify the data attribute of a link in the navigation bar and compare it to the current title of the page.

I then want to see if the current page title **contains** the anchor tags data attribute and if so `addClass("active");` if the result is true. A key requirement is it to **not match case** as well.

Here is my corresponding `html` and `javascript`

```
        <ul class="top nav">
            <li><a class="first" href="http://www.fishwebsite/" name="link" data-index="Home">Home</a></li>             
            <li><a href="http://www.fishwebsite/about-us/" name="link" data-index="About us">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.fishwebsite/our-boats/" name="link" data-index="Our boats">Our boats</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.fishwebsite/product-list/" name="link" data-index="Product list">Product list</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.fishwebsite/recipes/" name="link" data-index="Recipes">Recipes</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.fishwebsite/contact/" name="link" data-index="Contact us">Contact us</a></li>               
        </ul>
```

And the javascript currently is

```
    var current_title = (document).attr("title");

    $("a[name=link]").each(function () { 

        var a = $("a[name=link]").attr("data-index"); 

        //returns true or false...
        var exists = current_title.test(a);

        if(exists) {
            $(a).addClass("active");
        } 

        else {
          //false statement..do whatever
        }

    });
```

Can someone help me along? I have a CSS style for an active link which will be different to usual nav items hence giving the impression its the 'active' page on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Change to $(this) in each function since, you are selecting each item.

```
 var current_title = (document).attr("title");
    $("a[name=link]").each(function () { 

        var a = $(this).attr("data-index"); 

        //returns true or false...
        var exists = current_title.test(a);

        if(exists) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
        } 

        else {
          //false statement..do whatever
        }

    });
```

Comment: I've changed to that but to no success :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this,Wrap your script inside document ready. and I changed your functions little bit.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var current_title = $(document).attr("title");

$("a[name=link]").each(function () { 

    var a = $(this).attr("data-index"); 

    //returns true or false...
    var exists = current_title.indexOf(a)>0;

    if(exists) {
        $(a).addClass("active");
    } 

    else {
      //false statement..do whatever
    }

    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now fixed the issue thanks to both posts above. Here is the complete HTML and JS.

```
<ul class="top nav">
        <li><a class="first" href="http://www.fishwebsite/" name="link" data-index="Home">Home</a></li>             
        <li><a href="http://www.fishwebsite/about-us/" name="link" data-index="About us">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.fishwebsite/our-boats/" name="link" data-index="Our boats">Our Boats</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.fishwebsite/product-list/" name="link" data-index="Product list">Product list</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.fishwebsite/recipes/" name="link" data-index="Recipes">Recipes</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.fishwebsite/contact/" name="link" data-index="Contact us">Contact us</a></li>               
    </ul>
```

And the Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var current_title = $(document).attr("title");

    $("a[name=link]").each(function() { 

        var a = $(this).attr("data-index"); 

        var exists = current_title.indexOf(a)>0;

        if(exists) {
            $(this).addClass("active")
        } 

        else {
           // $(this).removeClass('active');
        }

    });

});
```

Adding `$(this)` instead of `(a)` was a great tip as it singled out the link in question and Nishans addition of `>0` finished off the working code.

**Drawbacks**

Case sensitivity. The `data-index` value **must** match the case of the title exactly or the `active` link will not be assigned.

Longer anchor tags with the addition of a `name` attribute and `data-index`.

**Advantages**

An efficient way to assign an active link with `jQuery` and `title` and `data-index` can be matched up in case very easily when building websites. No server side, messy PHP intervention to assign an active link.